# Intergrating Django with React Frontend: Is a REST API Needed

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

so I am trying to connect my back-end Django to my front-end React. Now the front-end react is essentially completed and running on a node server to check it out. I want to integrate it into my Django to use as a back-end. My first thing i want to do is set up the login and register page. I have most of the django back-end done but now i need to get the information like the email and password from the React to Django.

The HTML for EMail and Password

```
<form action="/authentication/" method ="POST">
    {%  csrf_token %}
    Email :
    <input type="email" name="email"><br><br>
    Password :
    <input type="password" name="pass"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    <button type="button" onclick="location.href='{%  url 'register' %}'">Register</button>
</form>
```

the react text field for just the email looks like this:

```
<TextField
              variant="outlined"
              margin="normal"
              required
              fullWidth
              id="email"
              label="Email Address"
              type="email"
              name="email"
              autoComplete="email"
              autoFocus
            />
```

Django

```
   def user_login(request):
       return render(request, 'user_login.html')  # page which user will login at

   def authentication(request):
       email = request.POST.get('email')
       passwrd = request.POST.get('pass')

       try:
           user = authen.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, passwrd)

        except Exception as E:
           # Where login fails goes
           message = "Credentials Wrong"
           return render(request, 'user_login.html', {'message':message}) # sends message login        failed
```

My first question is do i need to create a separate REST API fro the back-end? At the moment the back end is taking a simple test HTML file where i can enter the email and password which is as below, but if i wanted to implement it with react would i have to change out the .html for the .js file?

Comment: Please *ask a new question* when you have a new question to ask.  By vandalizing this question, you've made Emmanuel's effort in answering the original question useless: nobody is ever going to be able to find it again, because it's no longer attached to a question that it actually answers.

Comment: rolled back question to original

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For React to communicate with Django, it requires an api(Restful or Graphql) to work. Django has a nice way by providing django_resful api or django_graphene which works well with the Django model and reactjs for frontend. For me I use graphql for Django and reactjs, it way so easy and later I will send you a GitHub link of my project or you can  check on Youtube (justdjango).

Comment: whats the difference between restapi and graphene?